# How to allow google-chrome to open a local html file?

Tags: google-chrome

Using google-chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) on a MacbookAir Mojave I want to open a html file that is located on the filesystem and linked from another page i.e woth something like

```
<a href="file:///folder/something/summary.html">bla</a>
```

but when clicking on that link I only see the following text in the address bar

```
 about:blank#blocked
```

Is there any way to enable this/ allow this, so that I can open that page with one click?

So far I have to:

- Right click on that link
- Copy the link address
- Open a new tab
- Paste the link

to open the page. Can this be made ANY way simpler?

P.S. These local html files are generated by myself and do link themselves only to pages that are trusted. I do not see any security risks.

Comment: You should try again in a private session window. Personally when I got `about:blank#blocked` it was due to some extension, which means it didn't happen in a private session. I haven't identified which, or why it happens. Likely it's an extension that has access to every page loaded, and Chrome is figuring that it should not actually access a local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been disabled on purpose - security.  You can directly open file via `file:///` directive, but not via links.

The only way I found out is to install a plugin called [Enable local file links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld?hl=en-US).  If you want to check source code to be sure you can do that at [its github page](https://github.com/tksugimoto/chrome-extension_open-local-file-link).

It will enable you opening a local file when clicking on a shortcut.

Comment: I am puzzled: I have exact same Chrome version as OP and the thing that doesn't work for him works for me. The only difference is that I have MacBook Pro with Catalina. Any guesses why that would be the case? I do not have the extension you mentioned. In fact, I even tried disabling all the extensions I have, and still, I can reference a local HTML file from another one and it's opened by clicking at the link without any problems.

Comment: @isp-zax Hard to say.  Maybe some plugin did some changes?  Could you try it with a vanilla chrome?

Comment: I haven't been downvoting you, but that reminded me that I wanted to try your suggestion. It works fine on a vanilla Chrome in folders my local user has access to. It's a freshly installed Chrome on another MacBook Pro (although that's a newer version of Chrome 83.xxx - they seem cooking them weekly). My only guess is that OP has some file/folder permissions restricted.

Comment: @isp-zax I see.  I don't have an opportunity to try it on MacOS,  I tried it on Win and Linux where it does not work so I have to have the plugin.  Since the OP has accepted the answer it probably works for him?  Thank you for the information, I'll try it out if I get my hands on MacOS.  Of course, relative path would be better, but OP poster may have a reason why to open it via `file:///` directive.

Comment: This extension did work for me, but now it does not work for me anymore.

Comment: @Alex When did it work for you?  When it stopped working?

Comment: It did work form me shortly after the answer was given ( I tried the same day), and it stopped working between that time and May 22.

Comment: @Alex did you update Chrome or something else happened?  Did you change the access rights to directory?

Answer (score 2):

We do not use file protocol to open other html, css, js or image files.

"file://" requires absolute path and instruct browsers to download a file. many browsers will block the file.

just use `<link href="/folder/something/summary.html">Summary</a>`. Use relative path from index.html file location.

Answer (score 0):

The security risk is anyone can create a webpage with a link to local files on your hard drive. Say an executable. Disguise the link text and what displays in the status to hide what it points to.